# How to make a flutter app authenticate to a website?

Tags: android, flutter

I hope everyone is well. I'm new to Flutter and I was very excited about its potential, so I had the idea to solve a real problem I have at work. The point record. It's horrible and so I'm trying to create an app to do my own with overtime accounting, etc. Initially, it completes the UI, but the problem is in the algorithm.

Challenge description.

Although the query is web-based, there is no consumable API! However, I discovered that, when I authenticate on the portal, I can use a specific URL where I can download the JSON with the information I need. This occurs due to the session cookie created, which allows browsing only using the URLs that interest me.

In short, I've been stuck on this for about 3 weeks without having any more ideas on how to solve this problem. That's why I decided to seek help. If anyone can guide me on how I can solve this problem, it would help me a lot, including encouraging me to continue with my Flutter/Dart studies.

I hope someone can help or guide me by pointing out which approach to use.

Thank you all for the attention!

My attempts.

- I tried to manipulate cookies with Flutter, creating them in the app. Unsuccessfully!
- I tried to create a webview, just to authenticate to the portal and pass control to the app to obtain the JSON and be able to manipulate them. Unsuccessfully!
- Tried using JS to authenticate and copy cookies. Unsuccessfully!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package.

Use official docs:
https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro/

Everything you can imagine is available in this package.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I've already tried using it to solve my problem without success!